# What is the benefit of scaling the hyperparameter C of an SVM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

Please read the following [page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_scale_c.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-svm-scale-c-py) of the Sklearn documentation.

The figure shown there (see below) illustrates why C should be scaled when using a SVM with 'l1' penalty, whereas it shouldn't be scaled when using one with 'l2' penalty.

[image]

The scaling however does not change the scores of the models examined within the GridSearch. So what exactly is this scaling-step good for?

Comment: What do you mean it does not change? There are large difference in performance across different values of C and fraction in these plots?

Comment: On the linked page, the word scaling refers to the scaling of the axis representing C and not to the different values of C. The graphs C values and their associated CV scores are identical in the two upper graphs to the C values and CV scores of the two lower graphs. The only thing that is changed is the scaling of the x-axis. According to the article, this form of scaling is to be performed at l1-penalty, but not at l2-penalty.